# Получить идентификаторы объекта

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ol class="widget w-playlist" id="audio-post">
    <li class="js-open-popup" id="post-audio-li-1111"></li>
    <li class="js-open-popup" id="post-audio-li-222222"></li>
    <li class="js-open-popup" id="post-audio-li-333333333"></li>
    <li class="js-open-popup" id="post-audio-li-4444444"></li>
    <li class="js-open-popup" id="post-audio-li-5555555"></li>
    <li class="js-open-popup" id="post-audio-li-66666"></li>
</ol>
```

Есть объект **audio-post**. Как получить все идентификаторы `<li>` этого объекта? Как на JS отфильтровать полученные идентификаторы до чисел?

Чтобы на выходе получить:

```
var ol_id_li = '1111,222222,333333333,4444444,5555555,66666';
```

Comment: вопрос в том как из строки вроде `post-audio-li-1111` получить `1111`? Или как получить все `li` внутри `ol`?

Comment: Получить id каждого li в ol, отфильтровать каждое полученное значение до чисел, сохранить все полученные и отфильтрованные значения в переменную **ol_id_li**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var id = []; //создаём пустой массив для id
$('.js-open-popup').each(function(){ //проходим циклом по всем li
  id.push($(this).attr('id').split('-').pop()); //заносим в массив числа из id
})
var ol_id_li = id.join(); //преобразуем массив в строку
console.log(ol_id_li)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="widget w-playlist" id="audio-post">
    <li class="js-open-popup" id="post-audio-li-1111"></li>
    <li class="js-open-popup" id="post-audio-li-222222"></li>
    <li class="js-open-popup" id="post-audio-li-333333333"></li>
    <li class="js-open-popup" id="post-audio-li-4444444"></li>
    <li class="js-open-popup" id="post-audio-li-5555555"></li>
    <li class="js-open-popup" id="post-audio-li-66666"></li>
</ol>
```